# SCOPE_IDENTITY() returns null only for few records

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to find out what might be an issue here for so long. I have a stored procedure inside which I have one INSERT. Numerous records had this insert's scope_identity returned just fine. But for few it just returns null and hence, the next insert fails with an error(as this value can't be null in the other table).

In the logs I could see multiple requests coming in for this stored procedure at the same time(1 ms).

I guess the Ids are generated as I see a gap in the unique identities in the table at the same time as the multiple requests came in.

Could that be any issue with the scope_identity()?

Comment: I doubt concurrency is an issue. `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` will be remain `NULL` if no row was inserted, perhaps due to an error.

Comment: Right. My 2nd insert statement throws an error which I have in my logs. But the first Insert never threw an error. But the scope_identity is null. perhaps I need to look more closely into the insert statement.

Comment: Scope_identity stores id of last insert statement in current scope. Last insert statement did not succeed. Get scope identity after each insert if you need it.

Answer (score 1):

If there is a gap between identity values on an IDENTITY column and the gap matches the column's "identity increment" property value then the auto increment value was pulled to be applied during the insert, however, before the transaction completed something went wrong in the insert, a foreign key constraint for example. Once the next auto-increment value is pulled for the next record, it is gone forever even if a transaction fails. You need to look for errors during the insert operation.

Comment: Looks like my Insert is failing as I am trying to insert null value into not null column. Thanks for making me look into this.

Answer (score -1):

i had same issue with my web application where lots of request access the same table at same time to insert record, to prevent it you have to use "SQL Transaction" because what happened in your case your operation is too fast to execute and when insert command executing the table getting locked.

for SQL transaction use this helpful link : [SQL Transaction](http://www.dotnettricks.com/learn/sqlserver/sql-server-transactions-management)